# MS Graph todo tasks list API issue

Tags: node.js, http, microsoft-graph-api

I am call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/todo/lists in my nodejs application.

I am getting:

```
{
   "httpClient":{
      "middleware":{
         "authenticationProvider":{
            
         },
         "nextMiddleware":{
            "options":{
               "delay":3,
               "maxRetries":3
            },
            "nextMiddleware":{
               "options":{
                  "maxRedirects":5
               },
               "nextMiddleware":{
                  "nextMiddleware":{
                     
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "config":{
      "baseUrl":"https://graph.microsoft.com/",
      "debugLogging":false,
      "defaultVersion":"v1.0",
      "authProvider":{
         
      }
   },
   "urlComponents":{
      "host":"https://graph.microsoft.com/",
      "version":"v1.0",
      "oDataQueryParams":{
         
      },
      "otherURLQueryParams":{
         
      },
      "path":"me/todo/lists"
   },
   "_headers":{
      
   },
   "_options":{
      
   },
   "_middlewareOptions":[
      
   ]
}
```

But I need to get as per MS Graph API documentation:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.todoTaskList",
      "id": "AAMkADIyAAAAABrJAAA=",
      "displayName": "Tasks",
      "isOwner": true,
      "isShared": false,
      "wellknownListName": "defaultList"
    }
]
}
```

I created Tasklists and Tasks in my outlook tasks.

My code in default.js

```
 "graphToken": {
        "grantType": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
        "resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
        "requestedTokenUse": "on_behalf_of",
        "scope": "profile offline_access user.read calendars.read",
        "bearerStartWith": "Bearer "
      },
```

and

```
 "ms": {
      "graph": {
        "host": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
        "get": "GET",
        "post": "POST",
        "default-scope": "/.default",
        "user-agent": "mycompany/*",
        "me": "/v1.0/me",
        "calendar": "/v1.0/me/calendar",
        "todo":"/v1.0/me/todo",
        "scopes": [
          "profile offline_access user.read calendars.read presence.read presence.read.all tasks.read tasks.readwrite"
        ]
      }
    },
```

In index.js

```
MS_GRAPH_TODO_PATH = `${MS_GRAPH_HOST}${config.get('ms.graph.todo')}`;
const
```

and

```
msal.get('/authorize', processMSALToken, async (req, res, next) => {

        try {
            logger.info('Calling the MS Graph to determine has-access.');
            msGraph = await callMSGraph(req, MS_GRAPH_TODO_PATH, accessToken);
        } catch (err) {
            logger.warn('User does not have access to the MS Graph Service. ' + err);
        }
```

in todoService()

```
export const getTodoList = async (graphToken) => {
    const client = await _getAuthenticatedClient(graphToken);

    const response = client
        .api('/me/todo/lists');
        console.log(response);
    return response;
};
```

ApiV2.js

```
_router.get('/todo/lists', authenticate, checkGraphToken, asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    _logger.debug(`POST ${req.originalUrl}`, req.body);

    try {
        const graphToken = req.graphAccessToken;
        const result = await getTodoList(graphToken);

        res.status(StatusCodes.OK).send(result);
    } catch (error) {
        _logger.error(error);
        throw ((error.status) ? error : new Error(StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, _defaultErrorMsg, error.message));
    }
}));
```

Comment: Please share the code how you call Graph API. The code for the request itself.

Comment: You're 'response' is actually just the HTTP headers from the response. You need to handle the `data` event to extract the payload/body from the response.